# Springboot recursion method as Async

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, recursion

With (https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/) suggestion, where using @async annotation is suggested, I have come to know that methods from same class cannot be made execute async way, so then the question comes how we can write an async selfRecursion method, as then it will be from same class and hence I assume it won't work, so should we not use async annotation provided by spring boot and use basic threadpool.

What is the standard way to do it in spring boot service?

I have also seen that this annotation should be used with configs, is @Async annotation should not be used for service layer, where only calculations are done but then that interacts with repository layers sometimes.

Comment: You can have `@Async` in services, so what's the problem of a recursion?

Comment: I want to make recursion @Async, but as we know this cannot be used in the same calling class, will it work? as in recursion, the calling method and called methods are in same class, hence this doubt came.

Comment: Do you need each recursive call to go on new thread? If not, it will work. Otherwise create a method in another class which is async and returns back to your initial async method

Comment: I want recursion call to another thread. Isn't it ugly way to do it? is there any other smart way? Or we have many such things called Ugly smart way.. :D